# Codeigniter 4 - won't load from the database

Tags: database, codeigniter

**Edit for problem solved:**

After fighting this for way to long, and pretty much reviewing each and every Xampp apache and Sql setting in great detail, I found out ... that it had nothing to do with any on this. Nothing at all.

The problem was me putting a piece of code (a php function) outside of the class it was supposed to be used in ... so needless to say, it would never have worked.

Kind of a Homer Simpson moment.

**Original Homer Simpson moment:**

I have the following problem:

After setting up CI4 locally (with Xampp) I'm stuck at the following part of [the tutorial](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/tutorial/news_section.html). After going to localhost:8080/news I'm not seeing the news feed with articles. Instead, I get the error message saying that there is no news and it is "Unable to find any news."

I'm kinda at a loss here. I've checked the database information, and as far as i know, it is correct. I just added the DB name, user, password etc. Everything was going fine until this. This is the info for my database

```
public $defaultGroup = 'default';

/**
 * The default database connection.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'my-db-password',
    'database' => 'my-db-name',
    'DBDriver' => 'mysqli',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => true,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

I've checked the code from the tutorial, it's all been taken over correct. The paths etc are also in order.

Could anyone shed some insight as to where I should look for the problem, or where I should concentrate on? Is this due to bad apache mysql settings?

Comment: There's probably a problem with your view. I also suggest you not to use CodeIgniter 4. Is still in beta, is not it?.

Comment: @Kirasiris Thank you. I found the error. I made a mistake when I made the newsmodel. Apparantly I called a constructor outside of its class :-/. Lets call that a momentary brain-hickup. Thanks for the helping hand nonetheless.

Comment: happen to me too

Answer (score 0):

That's not a database error. It appears that part is working just fine. I suspect the problem is that there is no data in the `news` table yet.

Comment: I added the database and the seeds records with the SQL query they provided in the tutorial. Looking at phpmyadmin, it says that the records exist.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to fetch data from the database base on codeigniter 4.
Use this to fetch data from any where in codeigniter 4.

```php
$news = db_connect()->table('news')->get()->getResult();

// This should happen within you view
foreach ($news as $article) {

}
```

Then if you extend your model to the default model,
use this:

```php
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class NewsModel extends Model
{
        protected $table      = 'news';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        protected $returnType = 'array';
        protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

        protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email'];

        protected $useTimestamps = false;
        protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
        protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
        protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

        protected $validationRules    = [];
        protected $validationMessages = [];
        protected $skipValidation     = false;
}
```

In your controller use:

```php
$news = $newsModel->findAll();
```

This query may be modified by interjecting Query 
Builder commands as needed prior to calling this method:

```php
    $users = $newsModel->where('active', 1)->findAll();
```

If this didn't help you call my attention. I am here to help you get this set